# General solution and intervals (over which the general solution is defined)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I did a homework and I got x^2/(x+1)e^x + C/(x+1)e^x for all R (except -1), but they say it's for -1 < x < oo+. I don't understand how that makes any sense. Is there something I am not getting? e^x can never equal 0, so I think my solution makes more sense than their solution.

Comment: What is the equation and where is it defined on?

Comment: Ah is it because it's a differential equation and it isn't continuous between -oo and 00+? But why would we choose -1 to 00+ instead of -00 to -1?

Comment: the equation is x^2/(x+1)e^-x + C/(x+1)e^-x, i made a little typo

Comment: I mean the equation, not the solution.

Comment: It#s hard to tell which of two answers you post is (more) correct without knowing the problem statement ...

Comment: solve x^2y' +x(x+2)y = e^x. I don't understand why it would be pertinent in this case, since the general solution is all we need.

Comment: I solve $x^2y'+x(x+2)y=e^x$, but I don't get your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *interval of existence* of a solution is an *interval*. The set $\mathbb R\setminus \{-1\}$ is not an interval, it consists of two disjoint intervals $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(-1,\infty)$. So, $\mathbb R\setminus \{-1\}$ can never be the correct answer to "what is the interval of existence?"

Which of the two intervals will be the correct answer depends on the context. If you solve an initial value problem which specifies the value of $y(0)$, or $y(1)$, or $y(42)$, then the interval of existence is $(-1,\infty)$. If you solve an initial value problem which specifies the value of $y(-10)$  or $y(-2)$, then the interval of existence is $(-\infty,-1)$.

Simply put, the solutions of this differential equations don't jump over $-1$: they explode upon reaching it.